# xslt code help needed

Tags: xml

Hi
  Im working on soapui tool. It has generated a xml request code

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ChangeLengthUnit>
         <web:LengthValue>3</web:LengthValue>
         <web:fromLengthUnit>Meters</web:fromLengthUnit>
         <web:toLengthUnit>Centimeters</web:toLengthUnit>
      </web:ChangeLengthUnit>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also a xml resposnse code.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ChangeLengthUnitResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <ChangeLengthUnitResult>300</ChangeLengthUnitResult>
      </ChangeLengthUnitResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can some1 help me to write a xslt code to display the datas in both the request n response in a table format.
Also required is a java code that can call the xslt code in soapui.

Thanks in advance 
A.P.S

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244808/xml-response-table

Comment: Seems like a "do my homework". No question about a particular problem, just: "do all the work"...

Comment: pls help me out here. im new to al these stuffs.

Comment: Al least you should provide a desired output...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are new, you should start learning, and not asking here to make something for you. All the people here have got their experience by working and learning things.

Trying to help: a) read about XSLT, start at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_examples.asp). When you think you read and understand enough, try to make a stylesheet which simply makes comma-separated table from the request/responses. Ask here, when you meet difficulties and cannot find the solution on the web. Then b) read some topic found on "Java XSLT (processing) tutorial", read the API Documentation. Come back when you try something and meet a particular problem that you cannot solve.